# Storing and reapplying functions

Tags: python

I have the following situation; in some of the variables in our system we wrap them like so:

```
(What we write) a = "123"
(What the system stores) Value(a)
```

My question is, is there a way to write a function in which

- If a string enters the function, returns the string with the function applied
- If a Value(String) enters the function, unwraps the Value wrapper, apply the function, rewrap the Value wrapper, and returns the Value with the function applied?

Pseudocode of desired state:

```
def runFunction(fu, variable):
   try:
      # if string
      new_variable = variable.fu()
      return new_variable
   except:
      # if Value(String)
      variable_unwrapped = variable.value()
      variable_unwrapped = variable_unwrapped.fu()
      variable.value = variable_unwrapped
      return variable
```

```
runFunction(upper, 'Hello 123')
```

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand much until the pseudocode. The pseudocode looks reasonable, why don't you use *that*?

Comment: Try implementing something. It depends entirely on what "value" is. Also, just add the wrapping function to the Value class

Comment: @mkrieger1 It makes sense in theory, however if i use the 'upper' function as an example, its a built in function to a String, so if i passed a String into runFunction as so runFunction(variable.upper(), variable), that would work. However if I pass in a Value(String), variable.upper() would be a null function. Ideally I'd love to isolate the words '.upper()' and apply it to Value(String) once I unwrap it, which I'm struggling with

Answer (score 0):

Another possible design is what numpy uses. Have `Value` do all the operations for you, and wrap everything in a value first.

For example:

```
class Value:
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value

    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value

    def apply(self, func):
        # This handles calls of the form Value("a", func)
        if not isinstance(self, Value):
            self = Value(self)
        self._value = func(self.value)
        return self

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{type(self).__name__}({self.value!r})'
```

You can call the `apply` method in two ways, on a `Value`, or on a string:

```
>>> Value("A   ").apply(str.rstrip)
Value('A')

>>> Value.apply("A  ", str.rstrip)
Value('A')
```